# div: make a semi-circular disc

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to create a semi-circular shape out of a div.

Here is what I have tried.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  border-top-right-radius:100%;
  border-top-left-radius:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

I have also tried other combinations of `50%` and `100%`, all in vain.

I think it can be done be some combination of the `border-radius` and its variants, but I am not able to figure it out.
P.S. Also, let me know if it is not possible by this method and the how else can it be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border-radius calculated by using a percentage of the element's width / height, so unless the browser window is perfectly square, your border gonna be more elliptical, rather than circle. Here is my suggestion:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using one div only (as requested):

```css
div {
  background: grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

One more solution (using pseudo-element):

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

One more solution (using one div):

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 100% 100% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: That was slick! +1 :) Can it be done using only one div?

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `border-radius:50%`? ...But it seems to work either way.

Comment: Yeah, seems like 50% works perfectly. Please see an updated version for "one div" solution. The trick is to hard code the border-radius in pixels, cause as I said % will use containers dimensions.

Comment: Okay, but now I'll have to change the radii everytime I decide to change the dimensions.

Comment: Maybe you may want to use pseudo-element, please check an updated version.

Comment: @frederick99 Check an updated answer for one more solution please.

Comment: The last one is what I was looking for. Can you give some references or explain the terms?

Comment: @frederick99 https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius see the Example 23